# How to change the speed of Tkinter progress bar?

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

I have made a progress bar with python tkinter and I have tried changing the `time.sleep` and `range` but this hasn't worked to change the speed of the progress bar.

Here is the code to launch the progress bar

```
def launching(self):
    self.progress_bar['maximum'] = 100

    for i in range(101):
        time.sleep(0.05)
        self.progress_bar["value"] = i
        self.progress_bar.update()

    self.progress_bar["value"] = 0

def start_progress(self):
    self.progress_bar.start()

def stop_progress(self):
    self.progress_bar.stop()
```

Comment: Add the code that you have done so far to your question

Comment: Here's some documentation on the [`ttk.Progressbar`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Progressbar.html). It doesn't have a `value` option, BTW. You also shouldn't call `time.sleep()` in tkinter applications, use the universal [`after()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method to introduce delays.

Comment: why not call time.sleep() in tkinter apps ?

Answer (score 1):

To change value of progress bar in tkinter use `set()`

So try `self.progress_bar.set(i)` instead of `self.progress_bar["value"] = i`

Also a general note, in tkinter you can use `root.update()` (assuming your main window named`root` )to apply changes in UI instantly.

Comment: That's not going to work quite the way you expect. That's going to schedule 101 jobs  to all run in .05 seconds (_not_ .05 seconds after each other). I think this answer will be better if you provide a complete replacement for the loop.

Comment: Updated and removed this part until I test it again, edits are welcome